# This application does not support pin Windows

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, android-screen-pinning

Users are complaining that my application is not able to be pinned on their S7 Devices using Oreo. Neither Snapdragon nor Exynos. The error does apparently only happen since a certain point in time - but did not happen immediately after the Oreo update, and has not yet been observed on non-Samsung devices. I tried googling the error message `This application does not support pin Windows`, but found nothing relevant. What causes this error?

**Some information about the app:**

```
    android:noHistory="false"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:launchMode="singleTop
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"></uses-permission>
```

**And the startup:**

```
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

It also seems like I can't find another app that acts like this.

Comment: Maybe tell us more about "This application".

Comment: @U.Windl Added some information

Comment: Is your question answered in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html#pinning ?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the following line from your manifest files and your app will run properly on samsung phones:

```
android:excludeFromRecents="true"
```